# Spring Test Properties with JUnit 5

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, properties, junit5

I'm starting now to use tests with JUnit 5 and Spring Boot.
I have a Rest API with controllers, services and repositories and some utils classes that use `@value` to get properties from my `application.properties`. I'm not using "profiles" from Spring, just using the default configuration.

My Application Main:

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyRestApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyRestApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The class that uses `@value`:

```
@Component
public class JWTUtils implements Serializable {

    @Value("${jwt.validity}")
    public String JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY;

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret;

    // There's no constructors in the class.
}
```

The Main Test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyRestApiApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

My Test class that need the propertie:

```
class JWTUtilsTest {

    JWTUtils jwtUtils;

    @Test
    void getUsernameFromToken() {
        jwtUtils = new JWTUtils();
        assertNotNull(jwtUtils.JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY);
        String username = jwtUtils.getUsernameFromToken("token-here");
        assertNotNull(username);
        assertEquals(username, "admin");
    }
}
```

My project's architecture is:

```
main/
├── java/
│   ├── com.foo.controller/
│   ├── com.foo.model/
│   ├── com.foo.repository/
│   └── com.foo.service/
└── resources/
    ├── application.properties
    ├── banner.txt
    
test/
├── java/
│   ├── com.foo.controller/
│   ├── com.foo.model/
│   ├── com.foo.repository/
│   └── com.foo.service/
└── resources/
    ├── application-test.properties
```

I tried "@TestPropertySource" and/or "@ActiveProfiles("test")" in my Main Test class but that didn't worked. Also tried with "@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)".

When I run this test, my "secret" value is "null", which should be the value present in my `application.properties`

I tried putting "@Autowired" in my `JWTUtils jwtUtils` but it came out null. The @Autowired didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `JWTUtilsTest`  is not a spring boot test. Therefore no spring boot magic (like injecting configuration values)
2. You are creating the test instance of `JWTUtils` yourself. To have spring cast its magic you have to let spring create it (e.g. by annotating with `@Autowired` and making `JWTUtilsTest` a spring boot test.

Comment: When I added "@SpringBootTest" the Autowired magic worked! But I need to do this to ALL my tests? It doesn't seem right since every test he starts an Spring Boot Application.

Comment: Only slap it onto the one that need spring. And yes, it starts a spring boot application for that. That's why you should keep the spring boot tests and everything else carefully separated.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. I need to test my entire Spring Application and I have more than 40 controllers. It's going to be heavy to test all of them. I thought that just putting this annotation on the Main Method class would be enough to start an Spring Application for testing all of them. The `application.properties` that he's going to use it's the normal one? How we make a `application-test.properties`?

Comment: As far as I know you just have to create it. It does not need to contain all the values that present in application.properties, only the ones that differ in the test profile. Running your code via jUnit should select the test profile automatically.